# How can I use Selenium to Loop through and Scrape Several Pages of Data using OpenML?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

If we go to the link: https://www.openml.org/t/31#!taskruns you will see that there are ~400k results, I'm trying to scrape key info from all these results using Python 3.6.5 and Selenium. Attached is the code I currently have.

Picture of Code and Results that works fine for the first 300 results:

[image: 1]

My issue is, I'm only getting the first 300 results. If you keep scrolling down the link you'll note that there are way more than 300 results, I'm using Selenium because I thought it could parse dynamic information (i.e. more results come the more you scroll down).

My thoughts were that I wanted it to parse all the info on this page until it reaches the:

> Loading more... Not loading? Go to the next results now..

then proceeds to go to the next page and do the same thing until all 400k results have been scraped.

The HTML for the link I provided only has 200 results, then it contains the link to the next 200:

```
<a href="search?type=run&amp;from=300&amp;q=run_task.task_id%3A31">Not loading? Go to the next results now.</a>
```

Can I somehow create a LOOP where it would read the HTML and scrape the first 200 results, then goes to the xpath of the next 200 and keep doing that until all results are scraped?

EDIT: The relevent code is: (Im leaving the screenshot in order for you to see the output im obtaining at the moment)

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Zeshan\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://openml.org/t/31#!taskruns")

#This works for only the first 200
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="itemheadfull"]')
metrics = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="runStats statLine"]')
page_items=len(titles)

for i in range(page_items):
        print(titles[i].text + "+" + metrics[i].text)
        print("Output Number:" + str(i+1) )

#Trying to do it for results above 200: I'm not sure if this is correct
#This is the xpath to the "next page" of results
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="taskruns"]/div/p/a').click()

titles2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="itemheadfull"]')
metrics2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="runStats statLine"]')
page_items2=len(titles)

for i in range(page_items2) :
        print(titles2[i].text + "+" + metrics2[i].text)
        print("Output Number:" + str(i+200) )
```

Comment: Please don't paste links to screenshots of code. Post the code. The relevant bits of it.

Comment: I think, you no need to click on next button. it automatically loaded when you scroll down. You just need to fetch more elements and it's details.

Comment: @Murthi yes I believe so, but how do I fetch the details of the elements when they're not listed in the HTML page source? I'm stuck on that..

Comment: you can use some javascript to scroll down the page when you reach the 200th item. it automatically loads next 200 items.

Answer (score 1):

OpenML has documented APIs in Python, R, Java, and basic REST. I suggest you use those? That will be a whole lot easier. See the OpenML help page for documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have come across dynamically rendered page. The remaining rows other than the first 300 will be rendered once you do certain action (e.g. pressed the next button or move the scroll bar).

If you look at the network traffic, below is one of the HTTP request was sent:
`https://www.openml.org/search?type=run&from=100&q=run_task.task_id%3A31&dataonly=1`

That was probably fired through in AJAX manner through jQuery library.

I would suggest for you to play around with the AJAX query should you want to scrape the data, instead of hitting the main page.

Disclaimer: the website may change the way the backend service works at any time.